# How to replace an image in an embedded svg?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to dynamically replace an image in an embedded svg, I can get the current href attribute but setting it to a new one doesn´t change anything. Does this even work at all, as it is not a usual html img tag?

Here a (reduced to the essentials) code excerpt:

```
<script>
  alert(document.getElementById("image1").getAttribute('href'));
  // this works but document.getElementById("image1").setAttribute('href')='newimage.jpg'; doesn´t do anything
</script>

<svg>
    <image id="image1" href="test.jpg"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: `Element.setAttribute(name, value);` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
document.getElementById("image1").setAttribute('href', 'newimage.jpg')
```